# Perpendicular line to another line locked to a plane

Tags: geometry

I have a line, *A*, formed of a vector and a point, which is on a plane, *P*.

How would I go about finding the line, *B*, that runs perpendicular to *A* while also being contained within the plane *P*?

(I have two such vectors on the same plane, and need to find the intersection line between the two perpendicular lines from the two).

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: try finding a vector (N) normal to the plane (P). and calculate $$N\times A$$

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're working in three dimensions.

Hint #1: The set of lines perpendicular to $A$ form a plane.

> Then the line you seek is the intersection of this plane with your given plane $P$.

An equivalent approach:

Hint #2: Project $A$ onto $P$; now the problem is in two dimensions (the plane $P$).

> Then find the line perpendicular to $\operatorname{Proj}(A)$ in $P$; this line in the original 3-dimensional space will still be perpendicular to $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Say the line $A$ goes along the vector $\vec{a}$. The plane has a normal vector $\vec{p}$. The cross product $\vec{p}\times\vec{a}$ gives you a vector that is perpendicular to $\vec{p}$ (hence in the plane) and also perpendicular to $\vec{a}$ (hence perpendicular to your line).

Comment: Aha, that makes sense. I'll give it a go now. Thanks!